# Syntax error near end in Verilog

Tags: verilog, hdl

I'm writing a Verilog code to give all possible combinations of inputs to a 4:1 multiplexer. Here is the testbench for the same to test the code:

```
module FouthQuestion_tb;

reg d0, d1, d2, d3, s0, s1;
wire y;
reg o;

FourthQuestion mygate(.D0(d0), .D1(d1), .D2(d2), .D3(d3), .S0(s0), .S1(s1), .Y(y));

initial
begin
    $monitor(d0, d1, d2, d3, s0, s1, y);
    for(d0=0; d0<=1; d0=d0+1)
    begin
        for(d1=0; d1<=1; d1=d1+1)
        begin
            for(d2=0; d2<=1; d2=d2+1)
            begin
                for(d3=0; d3<=1; d3=d3+1)
                begin
                    for(s0=0; s0<=1; s0=s0+1)
                    begin
                        for(s1=0; s1<=1; s1=s1+1)
                        begin
                            #5
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

endmodule
```

However, I'm always getting the error "syntax error near end". What could be the possible syntactical mistake that is being made here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (aside from the missing semicolon after `#5`) is that the loop condition is `<= 1`, which will always be true for a **boolean** type (having the only possible values 0 and 1).  Thus it never exits the inner loop and instead runs forever toggling only `s1`.

You should instead use loop variables that can take on values larger than the one you are comparing, such as **int**.  To simplify, you can use a single loop variable that contains at least one more bit than all your boolean variables put together, then assign the multi-bit result to each variable through concatenation.  See the following example.

```
integer i;

initial begin
  $monitor(d0, d1, d2, d3, s0, s1, y);
  for (i=0; i<2**6; i=i+1) begin
    {d0,d1,d2,d3,s0,s1} = i;
    #5;
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey...I'm actually new to Verilog, can you explain whats does i<2**6 mean? Also what does the line {d0,d1,d2,d3,s0,s1} = i; actually do?

Comment: 2**6 is 2 to the power of 6 (the number of boolean variables you have).  And {...}=i assigns d0 to i[5], d1 to i[4], d2 to i[3], and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a semi-colon after the `#5`. It should have given you a line number to point out which `end` was causing the problem

Comment: There is no need of semicolon after #5 syntactically.

Comment: Yes there is a need. A procedural timing control is a prefix to another statement or the null statement. See _procedural_timing_control_statement_ in A.6.5 of the BNF

Comment: Alright...error removed but I'm not getting the desired output. Only the variable s1 seems to be changing, but not the others. Why is that?

Comment: How many times are you expecting each loop to execute? And why?

Comment: I'm expecting (and wanting) each loop to execute 2 times, which means all 64 combinations of inputs will be displayed using the $monitor and their corresponding outputs.